# Search key add on url with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a short problem. This is my html code:

```
<select name="searchtips" id="searchtips" class="form-control">
    <option value="http://88.99.78.54/category/bonnes-affaires/ameublement/searchkey">Ameublement</option>
    <option value="Electro ménager">Electro ménager</option>
    <option value="Extérieur">Extérieur</option>
    <option value="Hi-tech">Hi-tech</option>
    <option value="Prêt-à-porter">Prêt-à-porter</option>
    <option value="Jouets">Jouets</option>
    <option value="Animaux">Animaux</option>
    <option value="Divers">Divers</option>
</select>
<label></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Mots cles">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 buttons-section">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-tips btn-block submit-button">J'EN PROFITE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
  var go_to_url = $("#searchtips").find(":selected").val();
  document.location.href = go_to_url;
});
```

Ok, so when I select an category from options and click on J'EN PROFITE all works fine redirect me to the website. But when I write something on "Mots Cles" I want to add on my search key link: http://88.99.78.54/category/bonnes-affaires/ameublement/searchkey. So how can I add the text on my link?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: please intend code from next time onwards

Comment: + $("#someid").val()

Comment: Not working with that. When you type an words on search input will need to be the search key for the page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the field is populated and based on that, you can append it to the URL. Check the below code:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var searchString = '';
  if($("#searchString").val() != '')
    var searchString = $("#searchString").val();
  var go_to_url = $("#searchtips").find(":selected").val();
  document.location.href = go_to_url + '/' + searchString;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="searchtips" id="searchtips" class="form-control">
    <option value="http://88.99.78.54/category/bonnes-affaires/ameublement/searchkey">Ameublement</option>
    <option value="Electro ménager">Electro ménager</option>
    <option value="Extérieur">Extérieur</option>
    <option value="Hi-tech">Hi-tech</option>
    <option value="Prêt-à-porter">Prêt-à-porter</option>
    <option value="Jouets">Jouets</option>
    <option value="Animaux">Animaux</option>
    <option value="Divers">Divers</option>
</select>
<label></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Mots cles" id="searchString">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 buttons-section">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-tips btn-block submit-button">J'EN PROFITE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```